# Get physical file name of inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance, dll, reflection

I'm sorry to have to ask a similar question to one I've already asked and has been answered but I'm stuck here and was hoping that someone could set me on the right path again. (Original question here: [Get DLL's file name of inherited class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696926/get-dlls-file-name-of-inherited-class))

I have an abstract class called `PluginBase.dll` from which various other classes inherit. These are all compiled as different plugins for a server application. Let's look at one of these plugins, called `PluginMessaging.dll` which has a config file called `PluginMessaging.dll.config`

The method that reads the config settings is in the base class and looks something as follows:

```
private void ReadConfig()
{
    _runningDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(GetType().Assembly.Location);
    _pluginFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(GetType().Assembly.Location);
    _configFile = _pluginFile + ".config";

    // Do stuff here that reads from _configFile
}
```

The line of code that assigns a value to `_pluginFile` is what I got from the first time I asked the question (answered by [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever)) and it works fine, as long as there is only one instance of the `PluginMessaging` file and its config file.

What I'm trying to do now is to make two copies of the compiled plugin, let's call them `PluginMessaging_A.dll` and `PluginMessaging_B.dll`, each with its own corresponding config file, `PluginMessaging_A.dll.config` and `PluginMessaging_B.dll.config` respectively.

The problem I'm having is that, the server application iterates through all `*.dll` files in its Plugins folder, instantiates each one and calls the above `ReadConfig()` method for each. When the function is called for `PluginMessaging_A.dll` everything works as expected and the value of _pluginFile is *PluginMessaging_A.dll* but when the `ReadConfig()` function for the second copy of the DLL, `PluginMessaging_B.dll` is called, for some reason, `_pluginFile` again resolves to *PluginMessaging_A.dll*

It would seem as if there is some table in memory that remembers the `GetType().Assembly` information for `PluginMessaging.dll` the first time it is instantiated, regardless of what physical name it has on disk and retains that for any subsequent instances of the same DLL, albeit with a different name on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It would seem as if there is some table in memory that remembers the GetType().Assembly information for PluginMessaging.dll the first time it is instantiated, regardless of what physical name it has on disk and retains that for any subsequent instances of the same DLL, albeit with a different name on disk.

That observation is correct. The filename is irrelevant for the assembly identity.

You *think* you're loading two different assemblies, but the runtime determines you're trying to load the same assembly again - and doesn't load it.

> [MSDN: Assembly Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8xx4k69(v=vs.110).aspx):
>
> The runtime does not consider the file name when determining an assembly's identity. The assembly identity, which consists of the assembly name, version, culture, and strong name, must be clear to the runtime.

If you *do* want to load the same assembly from two files, you'll need to do so in separate appdomains. See [How to Load an Assembly to AppDomain with all references recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658498/how-to-load-an-assembly-to-appdomain-with-all-references-recursively).

Alternatively you can alter the name, version, culture or strong name and recompile again: then you'll have two different versions.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I'm afraid though that I'm not quite sure how to apply the solution provided in the link to my scenario but at least now I have something I can study.

Recompiling with a new name/version/culture isn't exactly feasible as I'm hoping to get to a point where any number of copies of a plugin can be made, and given unique file names, so that the behaviour of each is defined by its config file.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
_pluginFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(GetType().Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Comment: "Try this" is not an answer. Explain your solution, so it is clear that you understood OP's problem, and explain your code, so that we can verify that the code you pasted solves that problem. In this case, it doesn't: it'll return the executing assembly's path for whichever type you call it.